# Cucumber: Is it possible to read .feature files from a folder on the android device?

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, cucumber

I use cucumber to test my android app. Via the CucumberOptions I define where the feature files (test files) are located. In this example the files are in the 'assets/tests/*' folder.

```
@CucumberOptions(features = ["tests"], glue = ["com.myapp.cucumber.steps"])
class CucumberTestCase
```

Is it possible to define another folder for feature files, which is located on the device (e.g. the sdcard)?

It would be nice when someone would have the possibility to copy feature files to a specific folder on the device and when running the cucumber tests, these files would also be executed by cucumber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a pull request on github for this issue.
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-android/issues/32

Therefore it is not possible at the moment to load feature files which are not located relative to the assets folder. But hopefully soon.

Answer (score 0):

`@CucumberOptions(features = *yourpath*)`

You can specify any folder you want.

like:
`@CucumberOptions(features = sdcard/features)`

Comment: This does not work. I created a folder on my device and added a feature file in it (sdcard/features/somefile.feature).
I added the path to cucumberOptions: @CucumberOptions(features = ["/sdcard/features"])
But no tests were found.
I use the following libs:
androidTestImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-android:4.3.1"
androidTestImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-picocontainer:4.3.1"
Any Idea what´s wrong?

Comment: 1. Why are you using array of paths? just use `@CucumberOptions(features = "/sdcard/features")`;
2. Your path is incorrect. I bet you have an exception with something like "ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory". Ensure that you uses correct path. It should be like like: `@CucumberOptions(features = sdcard/features` not **/sdcard/features**

Comment: And regarding your imports. You need only `cucumber-java` artifact lib. Thats all. I mean exactly for that purpose

Comment: I have to use the array, because the code is written in Kotlin. In Java it is different. I tried different path variants: "sdcard/features", "/sdcard/features","/sdcard/features/", "sdcard/features/".
I get a warning: W/turePathFeatureSupplier: No features found at file:sdcard/features/

Comment: i guess something wrong with particular sdcard. Put breakpoint and try to open any feature file from this disk

Comment: My feature file is located in the following directory "/storage/emulated/0/features/test.feature". I tried to read the file programmatically and this is possible. When I add the same path to the CucumberOptions it does not work. @CucumberOptions(features = ["/storage/emulated/0/features"]

Comment: I also debugged the cucumber lib. For me it looks like, that cucumber looks only relative to the assets folder for feature files. Any ideas?